# How switch java version (SOLVE)

Tags: java, environment-variables, version

Hi right now on my PC works java 17

```
C:\Users\Dom>java -version
java version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I want swap on Java 8 for it in  windows environment variables i change path on `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\bin` (like on one guide) but thats not help.

verison java in my pc

```
- jdk-17.0.4.1
- jdk1.8.0_202
- jdk1.8.0_341
```

How i can change my java version on Java 8 ?

Comment: I'd make sure that the first element in `PATH` is `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` Then you can simply do `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341"` at the command line. Or use a batch file called 'j8.bat' to do that

Comment: I try but thats not help. Can i type any command in cmd ? like java -version jdk1.8.0_341

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

in file i type it:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341
echo setting PATH
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\bin;%PATH%
echo Display java version
```

thats change java version

Comment: You've already set `JAVA_HOME` so you only need `set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"`